# Android "Request Desktop Site" for HTML

Tags: php, android, html

I'm designing a website for both mobile and pc applications. The website however does not display certain key elements on android devices, so I have created a separate mobile website. Is there any way I can prevent the user form being able to navigate to the desktop site from their android phone (using HTML, JS, PHP, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this site:
http://mobiledetect.net

When you already have two different sites you simply add a php script with the classes and codes from PHPMobileDetection and if it detects a mobile device, then you redirect to the mobile site.

This also work, so far as I know, with the Chrome Feature "Request desktop version".